# "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed." in TokenAuthentication Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a token-based authentication system by following https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/.

But on sending a request, I am getting an error msg as a response:

> { "detail": "Method "GET" not allowed." }

Here is what I have tried so far:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

models.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):

    return render(request,'index.html')
```

Any help would be beneficial.

Comment: Your url points to `obtain_auth_token`. You showed us `create_auth_token`.

Comment: I want to `obtain_auth_token ` using DRF by providing username and password @KlausD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a post request.

Comment: Yeah, thanks got it.
I thought that we are fetching token so we needed to do a get request.